# Discord.py delete message log

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi I have made in discord py logs for deleting messages but now it is so when the message was deleted by a bot nothing is displayed can I somehow make that no message is sent when a bot deletes the message

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
        delete_message_embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f'{entry.user.name} Has deleted a message | {message.author.id}'
            , description=f"`{message.content}`")
        delete_message_embed.add_field(name='Channel', value=f'{message.channel.name}')
        channel = bot.get_channel(827128556722454600)
        await channel.send(embed=delete_message_embed)
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: “*can I somehow make that no message is sent when a bot deletes the message*” If you don’t want a message to be sent, why would you call `channel.send()` at all…?

Comment: There are no errors it works only the message that was deleted by bot is instructive

Comment: It should only be sent if the message was not deleted by any bot.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to add check if a user is a bot:

```py
if user.bot:
```

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
        if entry.user.bot:
            return
        delete_message_embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f'{entry.user.name} Has deleted a message | {message.author.id}'
            , description=f"`{message.content}`")
        delete_message_embed.add_field(name='Channel', value=f'{message.channel.name}')
        channel = bot.get_channel(827128556722454600)
        await channel.send(embed=delete_message_embed)
```